# Wildfly 11.0.0 final java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

Tags: spring-boot, memory-leaks, jboss, out-of-memory, wildfly-11

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace` exception since new deployment on production(Before this change we were using a separate jar for scheduling it was working fine but due to some network issue it was stopping again so we added scheduler and included into wildfly server with other war) env. So basically we are using wildfly 11.0.0 final server in which we have 4 war files and one of them has @scheduled - Or scheduler and it run every 10 mins. So generally we do stop the service of wildfly and start again after new war deployment, but after certain time (4to5 hours) application start slowing down and when see the console of server there i can see java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace as below :

`WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (default task-11) Failed to define class com.arjuna.ats.jta.cdi.TransactionScopeCleanup$1 in Module "org.jboss.jts" from local module loader @1e802ef9 (finder: local module finder @2b6faea6 (roots: E:\Data\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\modules,E:\Data\wildfly-11.0.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base)): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`

`ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-55) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component AuditLoggerHandler for method public void com.banctec.caseware.server.logger.AuditLoggerHandlerBean.publishCaseAudit(java.lang.String,com.banctec.caseware.server.helpers.SessionHolder,com.banctec.caseware.resources.Resource[],java.lang.Long) throws com.banctec.caseware.exceptions.CaseWareException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: WFLYEJB0457: Unexpected Error`

So then for each operation we get similar kind of errors with `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`

So very first i have removed plain code from @scheduler and used Executor framework where i have used 5 fixed thread pool and with this change we deployed again but again same issue is coming.

I am not sure what is causing server down again and again and getting this memory leak issue.

In all 4 war we used Spring boot 2.0.2.

Any help appreciated. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like Jprofiler to find memory leak. It works like a charm. Check out following link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=032aTGa-1XM

Answer (score -1):

You need to increase your heap space. And check if you have a memory leak. Please take a look at following link. http://www.mastertheboss.com/java/solving-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-metaspace-error/

Comment: Metaspace has nothing to do with heap space